# Cannot create Project using latest Meteor 1.6.1

Tags: meteor

I installed Meteor 1.6.1 using Chocolatey.

Then I tried to create a new Meteor project for the first time, I got below error

```
PS E:\> meteor create react_project
=> Errors while creating your project

While downloading blaze@2.3.2...:
error: unable to verify the first certificate

While downloading blaze-html-templates@1.1.2...:
error: unable to verify the first certificate

While downloading blaze-tools@1.0.10...:
error: unable to verify the first certificate

While downloading caching-html-compiler@1.1.2...:
error: unable to verify the first certificate

While downloading html-tools@1.0.11...:
error: unable to verify the first certificate

While downloading htmljs@1.0.11...:
error: unable to verify the first certificate

While downloading spacebars@1.0.15...:
error: unable to verify the first certificate

While downloading spacebars-compiler@1.1.3...:
error: unable to verify the first certificate

While downloading templating@1.3.2...:
error: unable to verify the first certificate

While downloading templating-compiler@1.3.3...:
error: unable to verify the first certificate

While downloading templating-runtime@1.3.2...:
error: unable to verify the first certificate

While downloading templating-tools@1.1.2...:
error: unable to verify the first certificate

While downloading ui@1.0.13...:
error: unable to verify the first certificate

PS E:\> meteor --version
Meteor 1.6.1
```

I also went through the https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7499

also tried setting below

```
set http_proxy=http://corporate.proxy.server.intranet:8080/
set https_proxy=http://corporate.proxy.server.intranet:8080/
```

Then also tried setting the registry using command before creating a project,

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ --global
```

Also tried below command,

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Still did not resolve my issue

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasted entire day trying to do so many weird experimentation. But finally one such experiment worked for me.

I am using chrome. So I decided to install "TOUCH VPN" as an extension, RUN it,  then tried to run the same command in my Windows PowerShell and VOILA! it worked, below is the snapshot of how stuff worked on my PC for such weird issue.

[image]